# Why am I getting this error: nomatch for 'operator<<' in C++?

Tags: c++

Please help me out on why I'm getting an error where I have mentioned the comment guys. I'm really stuck here!
What other details should I give exactly?

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include<person.h>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    cout << "Constructor Overloading Demo !!!" << endl;
    person vish;
    cout << vish.toString() << endl; /* I get an error for this statement though I feel this is correct */
    return 0;
}
```

person.cpp //constructor definition file

```
#include "person.h"
#include <sstream>

person::person()
{
    name = "vish";
    age = 25;
    //ctor
}

void person::toString()
{
    stringstream st;
    st << "Name: ";
    st << name;
    st << "& Age: ";
    st << age;
    prnt = st.str();
    cout << prnt << endl;
    //return 10;
}
```

person.h //constructor declaration

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class person
{
    public:
        person();
       void toString();

        //virtual ~person();
    protected:
    private:
        string name;
        int age;
        string prnt;
};

#endif // PERSON_H
```

Comment: Off topic: If you're really going to use `using namespace std;` **surely don't put it in a header**.

Comment: Well, for a start `person::toString` is type `void`, and I don't think  iostream's `<<` has an overload for `void`

Comment: @infixed is it possible to have such overload?

Comment: @Slava then there would be no point to use `cout << voidThing;`

Comment: @crashmstr I think it is not possible in C++ no matter if there is a point in this particular case

Comment: @infixed it will not get rid of compile error, it would not compile

Comment: @slavia That's why I deleted that comment.

Comment: @slava while you might be able to define `ostream& operator<< (void)`, I am unsure if it would be a good overload.  `void` is strange.  (CSB) I once inherted some code that worked oddly, because at the end of the function it did a `return somesystemfunction(param)`.   Code didn't do what it was intended. But it compiled clean.  Turned out the function was `void` and the system call was `void`, so no compiler warnings.  I think the optimizer just didn't call `somesystemfunction` because it knew the result was void.  But expected side effects of `somesystemcall`(I/O related) never occurred.

Comment: @infixed it would not be overload in this case as you cannot make statement `foobar( someFunc() )` compile if `someFunc()` return type is `void`. Return statement is different case, that was illegal before but now you can do that for templates to be more generic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As name of method `person::toString()` suggests it should return `string`, not `void` (which means that method does not return anything):

```
class person { 
   ...
   std::string toString(); 
    //^--------- type should be changed
```

of course you need to change that method implementation accordingly:

```
std::string person::toString()
{
    stringstream st;
    st << "Name: ";
    st << name;
    st << "& Age: ";
    st << age;
    return st.str();
}
```

> I realize that my function was returning void. but my question is: why does that matter ?

Your output to `cout` is this:

```
cout << vish.toString(); // endl is omitted for clarity
```

which is equal to one of:

```
cout.operator<<( vish.toString() );
operator<<( cout, vish.toString() );
```

whatever is available. This means that function or method `operator<<` needs result of call to `toString()` and it cannot accept `void`. If you just want to print from method `toString()` write:

```
vish.toString();
```

that would work fine (except method name would be still confusing, but compiler does not care).

Comment: I realize that my function was returning void. but my question is: why does that matter ? as the function is returning void, I'm printing out what I want rather than using any return statement right ?

Comment: I see now. Thank u Slava :)

Answer (score 2):

operator<< expects a string to be passed to it. Your ToString function is returning void

```
string person::toString()
{
    stringstream st;
    st << "Name: ";
    st << name;
    st << "& Age: ";
    st << age;
    return st.str();

}
```

edit:

The statement

```
std::cout << vish.toString();
```

is identical to

```
std::cout.operator<<(vish.toString());
```

The prototype for the operator is

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::string);
std::ostream& operator<<(int);
//...
```

The function expects a string or some other parameter as an argument.
Your function is defined as a standalone print function. So it should either be modified as stated above or called by itself.

The function name 'toString()' implies that the function returns a string representation of the object that can be used for anything, not just printing, so it should return a string. If the function prints the object it should be called 'print' instead of 'toString'.

Comment: I realize that my function was returning void. but my question is: why does that matter ? as the function is returning void, I'm printing out what I want rather than using any return statement right ?

Comment: Thank u user 2666293

Comment: Thank you for your inputs @Samuel. Appreciate it big time. Apologies for the delay in response.